# Interpolate object property from list response

Tags: azure, terraform

I am creating the following web apps with terraform:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "api-webapp" {
  count               = "${var.api_name_count}"
  name                = "${var.projectname}-${element(var.api_names, count.index)}-api-${var.stagename}"
  depends_on          = ["azurerm_app_service_plan.appservice-plan"]
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.stage-resource-group.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.appservice-plan.id}"
  location            = "${var.location}"

  site_config {
  }

  app_settings {
  }
}
```

This will result in 3 web apps.
Now I am creating a key vault for which I want to give the web apps access to:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "keyvault_policies_apis" {
  key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}"

  count = "${var.api_name_count}"
  tenant_id                 = "${var.tenant_id}"
  object_id                 = "${azurerm_app_service.api-webapp.*.identity.0.principal_id}"

  key_permissions = [
    "get"
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "get",
    "list"
  ]

  certificate_permissions = [
    "get",
    "getissuers",
    "list",
    "listissuers"
  ]
}
```

Saidly the apply tells me, that `"${azurerm_app_service.api-webapp.*.identity.0.principal_id}"` is not possible:

> Resource 'azurerm_app_service.api-webapp' does not have attribute 'identity.0.principal_id' for variable 'azurerm_app_service.api-webapp.*.identity.0.principal_id'

how can I access the `principal_id` of the web apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `"${azurerm_app_service.api-webapp.*.identity.0.principal_id}"` to the `object_id` as a list of all the `azurerm_app_service` ressources.

You have to use [element](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#element-list-index-) to get a single element from it with the current count as index like this:

`object_id = "${element(azurerm_app_service.api-webapp.*.identity.0.principal_id, count.index)}"`

Comment: Nice thanks, I tried `"${element(azurerm_app_service.api-webapp, count.index).identity.0.principal_id}"` and `"${azurerm_app_service.api-webapp[count.index].identity.0.principal_id}"` but both are syntatically wrong...
How is that evaluated or handled? the whole expression results in a list of principal_id, nothing more?

Comment: What syntax error are you getting ?  
I checked the terraform documentation for the ``azurerm_app_service`` and it says:   
> You can access the Principal ID via ${azurerm_app_service.test.identity.0.principal_id} and the Tenant ID via ${azurerm_app_service.test.identity.0.tenant_id}